# How to pre-load an array via ajax and use it for select2?

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

My general problem is that I want to have a Javascript variable which I then use with select2, to prepare the options  for a select multiple. I have a fairly large array (7000 objects) and just want to store that once in a variable rather than constantly polling the server with search terms. Here is what I got.

The HTML is simply:

```
<input type="hidden" id="group_a" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select at least two treatments">
```

Now, when I write the variable directly everything works as expected:

```
var treatments = [{id: 1, text: "you"}, {id: 2, text: "me"}];
$("#group_a").select2({
    data: treatments,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    multiple: true,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    width: "660px"
});
```

However, when I use ajax to load the array things get weird. My code to do that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/funny/url',
}).done(function(data) {
    treatments = data.choices;
});
```

I tend to get the following error unless I use the debugger to step through the code, then it works as expected. So could this somehow be a timing issue?

```
uncaught exception: query function not defined for Select2 group_a
```

My complete javascript looks like below and I've also prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fb1d0mt/8/) which shows the same error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var treatments;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/funny/url',
    }).done(function(data) {
        treatments = data.choices;
    });
    $("#group_a").select2({
        data: treatments,
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        multiple: true,
        closeOnSelect: false,
        width: "960px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax call is asynchronous, so at the time you are instrumenting the Select2 control, `treatments` is still undefined.

You could do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/funny/url',
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#group_a").select2({
            data: data.choices,
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            multiple: true,
            closeOnSelect: false,
            width: "960px"
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4x9u47m/)

Better yet though, I would do the following.

Initially set `treatments` to an empty array, and use a function for the `data` option so if `treatments` is changed, the changes will be picked up by the Select2 control. That way, you can instrument the Select2 control right away, and then update `treatments` with the data returned by the ajax call. Additionally, you could initially disable the Select2 control, and then enable it when the ajax call returns.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var treatments = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: '/funny/url',
    }).done(function(data) {
        treatments = data.choices;
        $("#group_a").select2('enable', true);
    });
    $("#group_a").select2({
        data: function() { return { results: treatments }; },
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        multiple: true,
        closeOnSelect: false,
        width: "960px"
    }).select2('enable', false);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4x9u47m/1/)

The third option would be to keep your original code, but make the ajax call synchronous. I recommend not doing that though. When you make an ajax call synchronous, you lock up the entire browser.

Comment: Doh, I guess the name "Asynchronous Javascript and XML" should have given it away... Option 2 is brilliant. Many thanks! I only moved the initial select2 code above the ajax call just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Thanks to @John S for the initial approach, but I couldn't get the select2 formatter to parse my array. Select2 box would tell me 'no results found.' I ended up running a for loop through my array and writing out the :id, :text hashes.

Starting with my json ajax call is an array of string 'terms':

```
// localhost:3000/search/typeahead_terms_all.json    
[
        "Super Term",
        "cool term",
        "killer term",
        "awesome term",
        "try term",
        "param term",
        "try name",
        "Academic Year",
        "grade average",
        "Hello Term",
        "Academic Calendar",
        "kinda cool term",
        "My Term",
    ]
```

Then the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var term_names_array = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: '/search/typeahead_terms_all',
  }).done(function(data) {
    // Here I iterate through my array of strings and write out the hash select2 needs
    for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
      term_names_array.push({ id: index, text: data[index] });
    }
    $('.report_term_input').select2('enable', true);
  });
  $('.report_term_input').select2({
    dataType: 'json',
    data: term_names_array,
    multiple: true,
    width: "500px"
  });
});
```