# filling a Select2 select box with an array populated by an ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I'd like to use Select2 for a select box, populated by an ajay query to an api with a single call to the api. There is no need to query the api again after every keystroke.

I tried to implement it using this thread:
[How to pre-load an array via ajax and use it for select2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498599/how-to-pre-load-an-array-via-ajax-and-use-it-for-select2)
but I still cannot get it to work after hours -.-

My code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var linkableSystems = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ulrHere'
            }).done(function(data) {
                linkableSystems = data.results;
                console.log(linkableSystems);
                $('#SelectLinkedSystemToAdd').select2('enable', true);
            });
            $('#SelectLinkedSystemToAdd').select2({
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function () { return { results: linkableSystems }; }
            },
                console.log(linkableSystems)
            ).select2('enable', false);
        });


    </script>
```

```html
<select id="SelectLinkedSystemToAdd" class="form-control"></select>
```

The api returns:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "text": "demo CLIENT 1",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "text": "demo CLIENT 2",
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to populate the select box with the select2 ajax call and it works. But I cannot get it to work so that it only does 1 single api call.
According to the console, `linkableSystems` is empty at first:

```
[]
​length: 0
```

and then filled by the ajax request:

```
(2) […]
​0: Object { text: "demo CLIENT 1", id: 1 }
​1: Object { text: "demo CLIENT 2", id: 2 }
```

Sadly, these changes are not picked up by Select2 as suggested in the thread I linked above.

Can anyone please help me with this?
If you need any more information, please ask!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that these requests are asynchronous.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ulrHere'
}).done(function(data) {
  $('#SelectLinkedSystemToAdd').select2({data: data.results});
});
```

Should do the trick, since you update the select2 when the data actually is available. In case you initiliazed the select2 before it's a bit iffy sometimes. You might have to do `$('#SelectLinkedSystemToAdd').select2('destroy')`and reinit the select with the data again.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the linked post. I thought select 2 would pick up the changes when using `data: function () { return { results: linkableSystems }; }`. But you solution works and is nice and short. Thanks!